# How to support importing .uasset files in game for content creators(UE4)?

Tags: unreal-4, mesh, skeletal-animation, import

I would like to support importing clothes(as SkeletalMeshes) and props(as StaticMeshes) as uasset files into game for content creators, which  obviously have not been packaged with the game.
Basically I am looking for a clean modding pipeline.

EDIT:
***TLDR:***
Is it possible to load .uasset files with `StaticLoadObject()` into game and use assets from it ***after the game has been packaged***?
Or does it only work with packaged files?

If not what function do you recommend for that purpose?

***not-TLDR***

Bringing in stuff does work well in the editor, using Rama's LoadObjectFromAssetPath, just by:

1. right clicking my asset in Content Browser
2. copy reference
3. and copy pasting the result to the path variable of the LoadObjectFromAssetPath blueprint node.

Well, I am not sure if it is going to work at runtime...

So I used my favourite search engine and put in some keywords and bumped into [this](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/202627/import-ressource-at-runtime.html).

Then I wrote some code(Blueprint Function Library):

```
void UFileDialogOpener::LoadFile(FString  from) {

    auto result = StaticLoadObject(UStaticMesh::StaticClass(), NULL, *from);

    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 150.0f, FColor::Red, "from: " + from);

    if(result)GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 150.0f, FColor::Green, "name: " + result->GetName());
    else GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 150.0f, FColor::Green, "no result");

    auto * meSkelMesh = Cast<UStaticMesh>(result);

    
    if(meSkelMesh)GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 150.0f, FColor::Red, meSkelMesh->GetName());
    else GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 150.0f, FColor::Red, "no mesh");

}
```

As per the debug messages StaticLoadObject does not find anything.
I tried feeding it the both of the results of righclicking my asset in Content Browser and choosing either: copy reference and copy path.
Neither of them yielded any result.

Not sure where I am messing up.

Anyways, just wondering if anyone can recommend a better way of doing this(code, plugins etc)?

Comment: Please use edits to add substantial new information or clarifications to your post, not just to shuffle content around to bump the question in the feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research and stuff I figured out, my best bet is using Unreal's [UGC solution](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/blog/new-example-project-and-plugin-for-mod-support-released?sessionInvalidated=true).
I think that would take care most of the heavy lifting for us, and for the content creators as well.
Besides I would appreciate any help on the above code and questions, just to understand why it does not work...